# How is SpaceX planning to avoid fuel sloshing on IFT3?

Tags: spacex, fuel, spacex-starship

SpaceX is about launch IFT3 and during IFT2, the booster exploded probably due to sloshing and an engine having something block its fuel supply.

What has SpaceX changed to avoid fuel sloshing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially we do not know, since SpaceX is not talking about it.

However, the kremlinologists in the crowd, who sit there with cameras 24/7 examining every weld and visible seam, have some theories.

Between the [Ring Watchers](https://ringwatchers.com/) and [CSI: Starbase](https://www.patreon.com/CSI_Starbase), [NSF](https://nasaspaceflight.com), and others (Apologies to those I missed) they come up with crazy theories that sometimes are even correct. Usually with amazing 3D models to prove their approach.

For this topic, Ryan Hansen Space, who does a lot of 3D Modelling the other uses has a suggested theory, based on the welds seen on Booster 10 after it was touched up.

Some amazing video so I embed the [Tweet/X here](https://twitter.com/ryanhansenspace/status/1766266398467104769) since it is impossible to summarize easily.  Anyone now how to embed just the X video if so, please edit in for me...

Comment: I've never heard the term "kreminologist" before and it doesn't seem to be a popular word as far as web searching is concerned (Google thinks I mean either criminology or Kremlinology, the study of the Soviet Union). I more or less understand what you mean from context, but where does that word come from?

Comment: @DarthPseudonym in the Cold War people in the West would closely study everything they could find on the Soviets in the open media and try to draw conclusions from it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Ah, I see.  That makes sense if it's a typo of kremlinologist.

Comment: Are you saying broadly, '… we do not know… ' or that you believe your links might provide useful information, or what, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: He is saying "People on the Internet, who have made correct guesses in the past, have made a guess".

Comment: @JörgWMittag got it right. Only SpaceX knows the real answer. These guys though have a compelling hypothesis.

Comment: Could you guys stick to useful Comments, please?

If JörgWMittag's personal interpretation happened to be correct, even that much could never have been confirmed without geoffc's personal opinion… and while everything might, nothing Posted by either necessarily has anything do with the OQ.

Can anyone say how 'People on the Internet, who have made correct guesses in the past, have made a guess' is more useful than 'We do not know' or that you believe your links might provide useful information?